# embedded link in email receipt to edit/cancel recurring contributions link only xml

Tags: recurring-contributions, iats

Using iatspayments with Drupal 7 and CiviCRM.  Recurring gifts are working properly and cron running daily.

When contributor donates - he correctly receives an email containing the following statement

This is a recurring contribution. You can cancel future contributions by visiting this web page. (https://www.iatspayments.com/NetGate/ProcessLink.asmx?WSDL)

You can update recurring contribution amount or change the number of installments for this recurring contribution by visiting this web page. (https://www.iatspayments.com/NetGate/ProcessLink.asmx?WSDL)

Both links don't work in all browsers

Answer (score 1):

That’s an old issue; please see here for details/solutions:

https://github.com/iATSPayments/com.iatspayments.civicrm/issues/192